# Can busybox unzip tool overwrite symlinks?

Tags: arm, zip, busybox

I'm using the Busybox 1.32.0 package tools in an embedded device. When I'm in Ubuntu based x64 platforms, the unzip tool packaged there can extract over a destination directory without prompting any errors if I'm trying to extract a symlink. However, in the case of Busybox, when I try to do this and there's already a symlink with the same link stored there I get this error:

```
unzip: '/usr/local/bin/sample.so.1' exists but is not a regular file
```

Sure it's not a regular file, because it's actually a symlink. But what I want to do is either:

- Continue with the unzip process omitting this files.
- Replace this files with the symlink files stored in the zip.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You could first do a `unzip -l` to get all the filenames, and pass them into a script to remove those files, such as `xargs rm -f`.

Comment: @alecxs, yes it does. Maybe I used the wrong sample: `unzip: '/usr/local/bin/sample.so.1' exists but is not a regular file`. Edited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't.

You'll have to remove it first.

This is the actual [source code](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/archival/unzip.c?h=1_34_stable#n945):

```
                /* Does target file already exist? */
                {
                        int mode = get_lstat_mode(dst_fn);
                        if (mode == -1) {
                                /* ENOENT: does not exist */
                                goto do_open_and_extract;
                        }
                        if (overwrite == O_NEVER) {
                                goto skip_cmpsize;
                        }
                        if (!S_ISREG(mode)) {
 fishy:
                                bb_error_msg_and_die("'%s' exists but is not a %
s",
                                        printable_string(dst_fn),
                                        "regular file"
                                );
                        }
                        if (overwrite == O_ALWAYS) {
                                goto do_open_and_extract;
                        }
```

As you see, no way to bypass that error.